# I keep getting "Error: npm.cmd ls -prod -json -depth=1 failed with code 1" when trying to deploy AWS lambda serverless

Tags: deployment, aws-lambda, serverless

Below is my terminal output.
Is there something missing in my environment or is there a conflict with node versions? I'm using node v.10 but the repo is using node v.8

I've tried uninstalling the node-modules and running `npm install` but still keep getting the same error.

I even downgraded to node v.8 but it wouldn't work with most of the packages so I had to upgrade back to v10.

Can anyone help pinpoint what the issue could be? Thanks.

```
$ sls deploy -f function --stage <env>

Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
Time: 15299ms
Built at: 02/23/2021 5:08:25 PM

                         Asset      Size  Chunks                          Chunk Names
{resource}/serverless/router.js  6.52 MiB       0  [emitted]        [big]  
{resource}/serverless/router
{resource}/serverless/router.js.map  3.54 MiB       0  [emitted] [dev]         
{resource}/serverless/router
{resource}/serverless/router [big] = {resource}/serverless/router.js 
{resource}/serverless/router.js.map
[2] ./node_modules/moment/moment.js 170 KiB {0} [built]
[11] external "https" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[17] ./node_modules/ramda/es/index.js + 328 modules 325 KiB {0} [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/index.js 12.6 KiB [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/F.js 324 bytes [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/T.js 321 bytes [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/__.js 739 bytes [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/add.js 444 bytes [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/curryN.js 1.62 KiB [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/addIndex.js 1.65 KiB [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/adjust.js 1.35 KiB [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/all.js 1.12 KiB [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/max.js 445 bytes [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/bind.js 1.05 KiB [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/keys.js 1.96 KiB [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/map.js 2 KiB [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/path.js 757 bytes [built]
  | ./node_modules/ramda/es/prop.js 690 bytes [built]
  |     + 314 hidden modules
[43] ./node_modules/axios/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
[79] ./{resource}/{param}.js 2.33 KiB {0} [built]
[80] ./{resource}/serverless/config.js 549 bytes {0} [built]
[273] ./{resource}/serverless/{function}.js 82 bytes {0} [built]
[274] ./{resource}/serverless/{function}/index.js 2.17 KiB {0} [built]
[275] ./{resource}/serverless/router.js 1.35 KiB {0} [built]
[276] ./utils/JWTMiddleware.js 1.31 KiB {0} [built]
[301] ./node_modules/cryptr/index.js 1.78 KiB {0} [built]
[302] ./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js 276 bytes {0} [built]
[319] ./utils/CorsResponse.js 1.27 KiB {0} [built]
[320] ./{resource}/serverless/{function}.js 1.12 KiB {0} [built]
[323] ./{resource}/serverless/{function}/index.js 4.72 KiB {0} [built]
+ 1081 hidden modules


Error --------------------------------------------------


Error: npm.cmd ls -prod -json -depth=1 failed with code 1
at ChildProcess.child.on.exitCode (C:<path to node_modules>\node_modules\serverless-webpack\lib\utils.js:91:16)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

Get Support --------------------------------------------
    Docs:          docs.serverless.com
    Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
    Issues:        forum.serverless.com

Your Environment Information ---------------------------
    Operating System:          win32
    Node Version:              10.23.3
    Framework Version:         1.60.5
    Plugin Version:            3.2.7
    SDK Version:               2.2.1
    Components Core Version:   1.1.2
    Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing `node_modules` **AND** `package-lock.json`, followed by `npm install` worked for me.

Comment: `npm install` is very dependent on the package manager you are using. If the codebase uses yarn/lerna running npm install is less than ideal.

Comment: I recommend Try deleting `package-lock.json` first and deploying again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using `serverless-bundle` instead of `serverless-webpack`. The mistake for me was with an extra field in the `custom.bundle` field in `serverless.yml`

*Extra `webpack` field*

```yaml
    custom:
      bundle:
        linting: false
    
        webpack:
           webpackConfig: webpack.config.js
           packager: "yarn"
```

*Without the extra `webpack` field*

```yaml
    custom:
      bundle:
        linting: false
        webpackConfig: webpack.config.js
        packager: "yarn"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when running "always" auto-attach debugger in VSCode. I fixed the issue by disabling auto-attach before running `sls package`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue with a npm package called `typeorm-seeding` that I installed as normal dependency altough it should have been a dev dependency. I also used webpack and it seems that the bundling failed for this package for whatever reason.
So my advice for others would be to check your recently installed dependencies and see if they are supposed to be a dev dependency or not even included at all.